# Riot games json array outputs blank

Tags: php, arrays, api, json

Im trying to test a script so I can get ranked info from League of Legends, but when I run the script, it outputs as blank. No errors or anything. Just a blank page. It is a simple script. I don't know why its outputting as blank. Any help? Thanks a bunch!

```
// lets get all le info
// ranked stats
$json = json_decode('https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v2.3/league/by-summoner/35409868/entry?api_key=*snipped*', true);
// unpack the info
echo $json['rank'];
echo $json['tier'];
echo $json['wins'];
echo $json['leaguePoints'];
```

For refrence, here is the array:
[{"playerOrTeamId":"35409868","playerOrTeamName":"*snipped*","leagueName":"Malzahar's Gladiators","queueType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5","tier":"SILVER","rank":"IV","leaguePoints":44,"wins":22,"isHotStreak":false,"isVeteran":false,"isFreshBlood":false,"isInactive":false,"lastPlayed":-1}]

Comment: Just to be sure: did you replace `api_key=*snipped*` with your actual API key? Also, `json_encode()` doesn't accept a URL as its parameter. You'll have to fetch the contents of the URL first (using `file_get_contents()` or cURL) and *then* pass it to `json_decode`.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the latest version of the code that you're using? Create multiple checkpoints and debug it all the way: **1)** Fetch the remote URL contents. Did it work? If so, proceed to the next step. **2)** Is it valid JSON? Check with `json_decode()`. If it is, proceed to the next step **3)** Extract the required values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the wayy.. Wrap the URL with `file_get_contents` inside the `json_decode`

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v2.3/league/by-summoner/35409868/entry?api_key=*snipped*'), true);
```

Also, check if `php_openssl` extension is enable on your `php.ini` since you are making a `https` call.

**`EDIT :`**

You are accesing it wrongly..

It should be `echo $json[0]['rank'];` , You need to pass the `[0]` index before that as shown.. do that for all your other variables.

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/128521)

Comment: OpenSSL extention is enabled on my server

Comment: `$json = file_get_contents('https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v2.3/league/by-summoner/35409868/entry?api_key=*snipped*'); var_dump($json);` Can you post the output of that ?